# Ubuntu 19.10 zfs pool doesn't automount after reboot

Tags: automount, zfs

Preface - I have searched and tried previous solutions with no avail.

I created a zfs raidz1 pool `naszfs` using 3 external sata drives. The drives are attached via USB using the following enclosure: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07449Q74W

The pool works fine and I am able to use it however, whenever I reboot, I have to re-import the zfs pool using `sudo zpool import -a`

I'm relatively new to Linux I might have inadvertently done something to cause this. The only changes I recall making were to change the mountpoint using a few times using `sudo zfs set mountpoint=/my/new/mountpoints naszfs`. After which I reverted to the original mountpoint of `/naszfs`.

I have tried editing the `/etc/default/zfs` file with no avail. Or is it because I am using external drives?

EDIT: I found a workaround of setting up the following cron to run on reboot `@reboot sleep 5 && /sbin/zpool import naszfs`
It appears to be a bug as pointed out below.

Comment: Possibly the same this bug in Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zfs-linux/+bug/1850130 Essentially the zpool cache is being ignored or regenerated each reboot. I reported it 4 months ago but there is still no sign of any attention being paid to it. If you think it's the same bug, report in Launchpad that it also affects you so devs take an interest in it.